# react native scrollView Height always stays static and does not change

Tags: react-native

I build react native app and I use with scrollView for header with list of text horizontal.
The issue is that the height of the scroll view takes half size of the screen. Even after declared it as a style, it still stays as it is.

screen with the scrollView

```js
            <View style={Style.container} >
                {this.props.ExtendedNavigationStore.HeaderTitle ? <BackHeader header={this.props.ExtendedNavigationStore.HeaderTitle} onPressBack={this.goBack} /> : <Header openDrawer={this.openDrawer} />}
                <ScrollView  contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}} style={Style.scrollableView} horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    {this.renderScrollableHeader()}
                </ScrollView>
                <Routes /> /* stack with dashboard screen */
            </View>
        </Drawer>

    )
}
```

styles

```js
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import {calcSize} from '../../utils'


const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex:1,  
        backgroundColor:"#e9e7e8"      
    },
    scrollableView:{
        height: calcSize(40),
        backgroundColor: '#000',

    },
    textCategory:{
        fontSize: calcSize(25),
        color:'#fff'
    },
    scrollableButton:{
        flex:1,
        margin:calcSize(30)
    }
})

export default Styles
```

[image]

As you can see the black size is the scroll View, 
I want it to be small.

In routes stack into dashboard screen, the style:

```js
const Style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#9BC53D',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 35,
        color: 'white',
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    button: {
        width: 100,
        height: 75,
        margin: 20,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#ecebeb",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 40
    }
})
```

Comment: can u try removing the `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}` from your ScrollView? I don't believe it is needed

Comment: yesI deleted, it still same problem.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There is an existing limitation with `ScrollView` where `height` cannot be provided directly.
Wrap the `ScrollView` in another `View` and give height to that `View`.

Like,

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{height: 80}} >
          <ScrollView
            horizontal
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
          >
            <Text style={{padding: 24}} >title1</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 24}} >title2</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 24}} >title3</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 24}} >title4</Text>
            <Text style={{padding: 24}} >title5</Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

**snack sample:** https://snack.expo.io/HkVDBhJoz

EXTRAS: Unlike height providing width to a `ScrollView` will work correctly

Comment: Thanks, strange how little there is on this online.

Comment: Encountered this problem today, I just added a parent View with flex:1, it works as 2021, saved me, thanks!

Comment: Encountered this problem today, I've solved it by adding a simple View (without any style) as a parent element to the scrollview and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 54):

Use `flexGrow:0` inside ScrollView style

```
<ScrollView style={{ flexGrow:0 }}>
```

Comment: thank you man! this helped with combination of maxHeight for Overlay

Comment: The superior answer is not on top.

Comment: You are welcome @BorisMitioglov, Happy coding.

Answer (score 17):

That worked for me:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
    ...
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Considering the issue that you are using `fixed height` for the `header`, and flex for the **Routes** maybe, the *orientation for different devices would not scale well and would look weird*.

Therefore you may consider switching it to the `flex`

Here is the example by adding `flexGrow` to the `styles` of the `ScrollView` since it accepts [view props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#props)

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0.05, backgroundColor: 'red', paddingTop: 50 }} horizontal>
    <View style={{ width: 100 }}><Text>Label</Text></View>
    <View style={{ width: 100 }}><Text>Label</Text></View>
    <View style={{ width: 100 }}><Text>Label</Text></View>
    <View style={{ width: 100 }}><Text>Label</Text></View>
    <View style={{ width: 100 }}><Text>Label</Text></View>
  </ScrollView>
  <View style={{ flex: 0.95, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
</View>
```

and here's the link to the [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/BJ3-ATUiM)

Answer (score 3):

Setting minHeight: int, maxHeight: int to ScrollView should work where int is height in pixels.
example below

```
<ScrollView style={{ minHeight: 280, maxHeight: 260}}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `maxHeight` inside scrollview style

```
  <ScrollView style={{ maxHeight: 40 }}>•••</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

<ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0.5 }}>

....

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TouchableOpacity
   activeOpacity={1}
   style={modalStyles.childrenModalContainer}>
   <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
     <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>{children}</View>
   </ScrollView>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This work perfectly for me, you can try it

```
<ScrollView
      horizontal
      style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
           <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}>
                 horizontal content here}
           </View>
</ScrollView>
```